# Test http post w/o a client?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, http, http-post

I'm building a data management system. In the end it will be sending SQLite data via http post method to an instance. I will not be building this web datadase and it wont be ready for some time. However I would like to continue my production of the app and get the http post methods set up correctly.

Is there a way to test http methods without already having a receiving client already set up? 
Maybe a public client exists for this purpose?

I want to continue production (and testing) to the point so that when the web database is finally built all I need to do is essentially plug in the new url in my code. Is there anyway I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask it [google](http://www.google.com.ua/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=http%20post%20test%20server&pbx=1&oq=http%20post%20test&aq=2&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=1090l2007l0l4099l6l6l0l0l0l0l334l1704l2-4.2l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=29061f0e3f3de7b3&biw=1920&bih=979&pf=p&pdl=300)

Example [Henry's HTTP Post Dumping Server](http://posttestserver.com/).

Comment: Great-I don't know why I never came across that in my researching-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stub the posting class, implementing an interface. Use it directly, or use something like Guice to inject it.

You can always set up a dev DB service, and should, but a stub may be sufficient for most of your dev.